# How to solve dll missing in perl script?

Tags: perl

I installed perl 5.14 version just before, when I executed script display errors perl58.dll missing. How can solve the problem..

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: are you sure you don't have an old version of Perl in PATH?

Comment: Which perl distribution did you install?

Comment: yes, I checked perl -V

Comment: yes, I checked perl version, it 5.14 display but why errors message come during execuation...

Comment: I installed perl 5.14 version binary buid 1405

Comment: Are you sure you're trying to run a perl script (text file ending in .pl, plx or similar) and not a 'dependent' perlapp executable built on perl 5.8 (ends in .exe)?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that the thing you're describing as a 'perl script' is actually an executable built from a perl script using ActiveState's perlapp with the --dependent flag.  By default, perlapp executables are self contained, but the perl{version number here}.dll can be left out to save space.

Possible courses of action (roughly in order of ease + sanity):

- Get the original source from the guy who wrote it, & just run it.
- Get the guy who wrote it to update the perlapp executable to a non-dependent version or a version that runs under your installed version of ActivePerl.
- Pony up for ActiveState's 'business' subscription to download & install ActivePerl 5.8 (and no other version) on that machine.
- Find a copy of the perl58.dll and place it where windows will find it.  (may require subscription, or the guy who built the perlapp may have a copy lying about)
- Extract the original script from within the .exe and either build a newer (and non-dependent) perlapp or just run it from the source as Larry intended.

Depending on what options were used to build the perlapp executable you may have the origional source lying about in a temp directory.  Otherwise I believe you may be able to open it up with a program that understands .zip files, but I've never tried this.

---

It is also *possible* that you've got a directory in your path that contains a v5.8 perl.exe but not it's accompanying .dll and that you've asked your newly installed v5.14 perl not to place its directories at the beginning of your path.  I don't expect this is the case.